# Shopify and jQuery: how to change custom value using product variant drop down select menu

Tags: jquery, shopify

This is my first go around with Shopify. So far, so good. I am not using the Shopify shopping cart, however. I am using a third-party company called Shopatron for fulfillment and they provide their own shopping cart functionality via some basic API's. Basically, what happens is Shopatron provides the SKU. When I create a product in Shopify, I use that SKU and then call it using the following code for Shopatron's "Add to Cart" button on the product.liquid page:

```
<tron:ATCButton part_number="{{ product.variants.first.sku }}"></tron:ATCButton>
```

This works just fine and passes the SKU to the Shopatron cart. However, I need to add Shopify variants to some items which means there will be a different SKU based on the drop-down menu selection (the drop-down menu will obviously be a Shopify item). I need to know how to change the "{{ product.variants.first.sku }}" value so that it updates the SKU based on the drop-down selection.

I'm assuming this can be done with jQuery but I'm not sure how to tie it together. Any help would be GREATLY appreciated! There is Shopatron API reference at http://developer.shopatron.com/api under the e-commerce section although I think this is a Shopify thing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

shopify has a

```
new Shopify.OptionSelectors("product-select", { product: {{ product | json }},onVariantSelected: selectCallback });
```

so if you create a function called

```
var selectCallback = function(){
    if (variant) {

      if (variant.available) {

        $("#shptrn_addToCart input[name=partNumber]").val(variant.sku);
      }
    }
};
```

that should correctly set the sku for your shopatron add to cart button

Comment: Thank you very much for that info. Looks simple enough BUT I don't have control over the drop down other than to add the item information in the CMS GUI. In other words, I can't add data-part=... to the menu. Unless I'm misunderstanding? Are you saying that I only have to add `data-part="{{product.variants.sku}}"` to the menu via the hard code just once? I assume it to mean it has to be a value for each item which would defeat the purpose of the CMS. Hope that makes sense. I'll try some things and see how it goes. Thanks!

Comment: well the pattern is pretty much the same. To break it down you would need to know the dynamic part number that is being selected from the drop down and that's pretty much it. As long as you can determine that you can solve the problem. If you can please post the drop down code or what it looks like.

Comment: `<select class="single-option-selector" id="product-select-option-0">

Comment: I think this is what you want to see? The class and id are assigned by the CMS. This view is from my inspector.
<br/><br/>

`<select class="single-option-selector" id="product-select-option-0">
<option value="complete set">Complete Set</option>
<option value="towel only">Towel Only</option>
</select>`
<br/><br/>
I'll make a second comment so you can see the source code view.

Comment: `<form id="add-item-form" action="/cart/add" method="post" class="variants clearfix">
        <div class="select clearfix">
          <select id="product-select" name='id'>
            <option value="568917081">Complete Set - $ 84.00</option>
            <option value="569524773">Bath Towel Only - $ 50.00</option>
          </select>
        </div>
        <div class="purchase-section multiple">
          <div class="purchase">
            <tron:ATCButton part_number="31BLOSMBBATHCE"></tron:ATCButton>
          </div> <!-- /.purchase -->
        </div> <!-- /.clearfix -->
      </form>`

Comment: That's a mess. I'm still trying to learn the formatting options. Sorry.

Comment: how does that relate to the part number again? so if I were a buyer and I select towel, where is the towel SKU that shopatron understands?

Comment: I think you're referring to the single-line comment I made in error. I'm a rookie at this so I'm struggling with the comment formatting. My apologies. Anyhow, there is no correlation yet. I made the variant drop down selector in the CMS - that's the code you see in the first comment. The second is the source code view of what the CMS generated. I hope that makes sense.

Comment: please add an Id to the <tron:ATCButton id="purchase" part_number="">

after that I think you should be good to go with the revised code I provided

Comment: I'll give it a go. Thank you very much. You've been a huge help. Sorry for the messy formatting. I'll get that part figured out soon. :)

Comment: no worries, glad to help. The only problem I could forsee is that tron:ATCButton does not respect you adding a id attribute. I hope it will take it, but worse case-scenario come back and we'll figure something out

Comment: I'm getting an error. 'undefined' is not a function (evaluating '$("#product-select").on'). Is there a way I can show you the code privately? It sounds like you have Shopify experience and would know exactly what and where to look.

Comment: I got rid of the error by updating to jQuery 1.7 (for the .on support). But still no luck with the SKU change. :(

Comment: can you put this in your code to see if you at least get the correct SKU?

`$("#product-select").on("change", function(e){
    var sku = $(e.currentTarget).val();
    alert(sku);
});`

Comment: It's not firing the alert. It looks right and I understand the logic of what you're trying to do - I just can't figure out why it's not happening.

`<select id="product-select" name='id' data-part="{{product.variants.sku}}">`

Comment: that doesn't match the select in the above snippet you posted. Does data-part dynamically change based on the option you selected?

Comment: The way their code is generated is confusing to me. I can handle some jQuery stuff and this doesn't seem like it should be terribly difficult but it has me baffled. There are two `<select>` menus in the code but only one shows on screen. They have similar but different `<option>` values. One of the select names (ID) is product-select and the other is product-select-option-0. I've tried to fire an alert (and console.log) on both drop downs on ANY change and nothing happens. Nothing changes. Is there a way for me to message you with the credentials so you can look at the actual code?